# FQL like "Subscriber List / Friend Subscribers"

Tags: list, facebook-fql, subscriber

I can't find how to select the friend subscribers like on http://www.facebook.com/me?sk=subscribers&filter=1 The query

```
select subscriber_id from subscription where subscribed_id = me()
```

returns only public subscribers and the `connection` table isn't returning all the old friends.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/me/subscribers` endpoint to get data about who is subscribed to the current user (array of people and total num are returned).

> "connection table isn't returning all the old friends."

Theres no way to get a list of people that used to be friends but are not anymore, nor subscribed. That'd be a privacy issue.

Comment: Thanks Tommy, I tried the graph and the result is the same: 
It doesn't show the former friends subscribed to me, like on  http://www.facebook.com/me?sk=subscribers&filter=1

Comment: Not all functionality on the website is available via the API.